# Undervoltage protection circuit design review

Tags: circuit-analysis, protection, undervoltage

I want to design an undervoltage protection circuit. The nominal supply voltage is \$48 V\$ and the maximum load current is about \$ 0.5A\$. If the supply drops to about \$39 V\$ or below, a P-FET shall cut off the circuit.

I came up with the following design:

[image]

Now I simulate a supply voltage sweep from \$0V\$ to \$48V\$, which gives me the following results:

[image]

It's a little hard to see from the graph but the voltage threshold is at about \$39 V\$ where I want to have it.

The requirements for the circuit are the following:

- As few components as possible due to very tight packaging space on PCB
- \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ must be \$30 k\Omega\$ and \$120 k\Omega \$ respectively
- A P-Channel MOSFET must be used in the power path

Is there anything that can be improved for this circuit? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does it need a P-channel mosfet or is it enough if it cuts the high side? Meaning that it will stop the positive voltage from getting to load, in stead of  cutting low side / GND.

Comment: yes it needs to be a P-FET because I have also designed a soft-start circuit (not shown) with the same fet.

Comment: What about using TL431 instead of a zener diode and a bipolar transistor? TL431 has better characteristics and cheaper BOM cost.

Comment: @JLCPCBEngineer interesting suggestion but it seems it only works up to \$36V\$

Comment: It makes sense.

Comment: Why are the values of R1 and R2 restricted? Why must you use a P-MOSFET? Where are these requirements coming from?

Comment: The threshold voltage will not be well defined in real-life mainly due to the low Zener diode current.

Comment: @G36 would you have any suggestion for improvement?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have also realized a slow-start circuit (not shown) with this P-FET, which rely on R1 and R2 together with a capacitor to soft-start the P-FET.

Comment: Your threshold voltage tolerance will be dominated by the tempco and initial tolerance of the zener diode. R4 is pulling very little current through it which will exacerbate the tolerance. If +/- many volts is OK for you, then maybe it will do. Use Q2 as a cascode to increase the voltage output of a TL431, and feed it with a voltage divider. Much better tolerance.

Comment: @Neil_UK could you give an example schematic for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjsUhd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And the threshold point is equal to:

\$V_{TH} \approx (1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2})V_{REF} \approx  (1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2})*2.5V\$

Comment: Thats interessting. Thanks. For M1 I can add a Csg and Cdg capacitor to realize a soft-start of M1.

Comment: I think that adding a capacitor will change the threshold voltage.

Comment: I adapted the schematic a bit and added the caps. They do not seem to interfere with the threshold too much. M1 now starts within ~2ms to pre-charge a 10uF cap, which is used for decoupling the load.

Comment: @G36 You might say something in your answer about R8's hysteresis. Nice idea, but it might depend on the stiffness of V1 and so have to be tuned. I went the whole hog in my design and made the PFET and the TL431 effectively a thyristor, so that they shut off totally when undervoltage was reached. Note that TL431 uses quite high input current. TLV431 uses much lower current, but is lower voltage so will need a lower R3 to keep its anode voltage down.

Comment: in the meantime I realized that all this analogue effort is just for learning purpose, tbh. Even with a fancy schematic, I will always have issues with temperature dependencies. I found that implementing a high-side overcurrent protection IC with reverse voltage control, inrush control, OVLP, UVLO, enable, and what not is the way to go. Only issue is part availability these days.