# I tried TL431 undervoltage protection for EV battery 48V

Tags: power, power-electronics

[image]

My purpose is to make cutoff circuit that will cut battery voltage before 40 V else after 40 V it will be in working.

Above circuit I tried and it’s working fine but I'm confused because as per the datasheet  TL431 cathode volt is 36 VDC max.

Just let me know if anyone can help me to make sure this circuit is theoretically correct
because during my test TL431 cathode was getting 38 V on 39 V input. 1 V drop at R1 (10k) resistor that is exceeding the limit.

Comment: 40V will damage the TL431. See here how you can reduce the TL431 voltage. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/606428/undervoltage-protection-circuit-design-review/606503#606503  or here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/627144/analog-circuit-for-battery-discharge-protection/627149#627149

Comment: Consider an N-FET to pull down the gate of the P-FET and a Zener clamp to limit Vgs of your P-FET.

Comment: The TL431 is the wrong IC because it has a linear output. You want two states: on or off. Therefore, you need an IC with a digital output. Such ICs include comparators and power supply supervisors.

Comment: If that is a Li-ion battery and your goal is protect it, a low voltage cutout won't do so. What you need is a BMS that cuts of the power if a **single cell** is low.Your circuit cuts off if the total battery voltage is low, by which time it's too late to prevent damage to a cell.